# Add metadata to XeLaTeX PDFs without using hyperref

Tags: xetex, hyperref, pdf, metadata

When using `pdflatex`, it is possible to add metadata to PDFs without using the `hyperref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfinfo{
  /Title (My very first paper)
  /Author (Gary Gnu)
}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

However, this does not work when compiling with `xelatex`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \pdfinfo 

l.2  \pdfinfo
             {
?
```

Is there any similarly simple way of adding PDF metadata to XeLaTeX documents without using `hyperref`?

(In case anyone is wondering, I am asking because (1) some journal and conference submission guides prohibit the use of `hyperref` altogether, and (2) even when I am not constrained by such guides, `hyperref` by default applies certain formatting and interacts with other packages in ways that I do not necessarily want and that I do not want to remember to account for and undo.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is set using the `pdf:docinfo` special

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\special { pdf:docinfo << /Title (My very first paper) /Author (Gary Gnu)>> }
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: The LaTeX team are working on some engine-neutral interfaces here: currently they are in `expl3` but low-level, I hope to have a more 'user-facing' set up soon